# slideToggle with classToggle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table and I would like to collapse the next line if I click on the header. Also, I would like to change the class whether the table is collapsed or not.

I wrote this:

```
$('th').click(function(){
        var $el = $(this)
        $(this).closest('tr').next().slideToggle(0)
        if($(this).closest('tr').next().is(':visible')) {
           $el.addClass   ('opened');
           $el.removeClass('closed');
        } else {
           $el.removeClass   ('opened');
           $el.addClass      ('closed');
        }
});
```

I am wondering if I can do better with JQuery ?

Here's the HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Line 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Line 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>date</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the css:

```
.opened {
    background-image: url("bullet_toggle_minus.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
}

.closed {
    background-image: url("bullet_toggle_plus.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
}
```

Comment: If you are looking for something similar to your `slideToggle()`, its called `toggleClass()`. If you are using [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) you'll need one **default** class, and another for modifying the state

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7xr2Lvpk/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) with multiple classes:

```
$('th').click(function () {
    var $el = $(this)
    $el.closest('tr').next().slideToggle(0);
    $el.toggleClass('opened closed');
});
```

Remember to set the initial state of all the elements by setting the class on the `th` like:

```
<th colspan="2" class="opened">Line 1</th>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r0xpbqea/

Comment: he needs to set this initial state on all `<th>` elements

Comment: Yep, so this deserve a -1 ?

Comment: did not mean to offend you with it and sorry if i did :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers

Comment: @AhmadAssaf no offense :-) ; but I think an answer like this is valid and not to be downvoted: has reason, code and demo, so...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr').addClass('opened');
$('th').click(function(){
        var $el = $(this)
        $(this).closest('tr').next().slideToggle(0).toggleClass('opened closed');
});
```

CSS

```
tr {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
}

.opened {
    background-image: url("bullet_toggle_minus.png");
}

.closed {
    background-image: url("bullet_toggle_plus.png");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Script**

```
$('th').click(function() {
        var $el = $(this);
        $(this).closest('tr')
               .next()
               .slideToggle(0)
               .toggleClass('closed');
});
```

**Style**

```
tr {
    background-image: url("bullet_toggle_minus.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
}

tr.closed {
    background-image: url("bullet_toggle_plus.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teh94dma/

Comment: this will only toggle class 'closed' on and off again, it will not do his desired behaviour by toggling two classes